# Paypal form - How to save fields as variables?

Tags: php, paypal

I have the following Paypal payment form:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="******">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="******">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="25">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
<input id="afield" type="text" placeholder="Name"</input>
<input id="afield" type="text" placeholder="Email Address"</input>
<!-- Saved buttons display an appropriate button image. -->
<input type="image" name="submit"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"
alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
<img alt="" width="1" height="1"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
```

My question is, how can I get the two inputs (id: afield) so that I can save them for when the user returns to my website after paying, I can use them. I am using PHP.

Thanks

Comment: cookies? PHP session ? database ? chose what you want depend on your needs

Comment: No what I mean is, how do I actually get them as a variable in the first place? The form action is using Paypal's script: <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

Comment: You shouldn't have 2 fields with the same id. Make them unique. Also, give them a `name` attribute. When the response comes back from PayPal it will come back in a GET or POST request. You'll have to figure that out. Once you know if it is a GET or POST request, you can access the data via `$_GET['name_of_field']` or `$_POST['name_of_field']` respectively. Just assign that to a variable. `$myVariable = $_GET['name_of_field'];`

Comment: yeah you will receive them as custom field along in the IPN

Comment: Not sure if it is clear or not but you shouldn't try to save them at this point. The form you showed us is the _outgoing_ request to PayPal. You'll have access to them when the response from PayPal (IPN) comes back. You can inspect the response and grab any of the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have dealt with this in the past.

First step is to fix the input field:

```
<input id="afield" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="afield">
```

I have corrected your HTML syntax and called the field `afield`

You then need to set another hidden field called `notify_url` - this is the URL that PayPal will POST the transaction details back to after a payment has been made.

e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://www.yourdomain.com/paypal.php">
```

Inside `paypal.php` you can then access `$_POST['afield']`

In case it helps, here is the sort of thing you need inside `paypal.php` - this verifies that the transaction details POSTed back from PayPal are genuine and that the payment was successful:

```
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
    $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
  $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
  if ($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
  } else {
    $value = urlencode($value);
  }
  $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// Step 2: POST IPN data back to PayPal to validate
$ch = curl_init('https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
if ( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
  curl_close($ch);
  exit;
}
curl_close($ch);

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0 and $_POST['payment_status'] == 'Completed') {   

  // payment has been verified

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field with the name **custom**

The only issue is this field can't be returned by Paypal in the answer, even in the PDT

Only can see this field in the IPN text

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#transaction-and-notification-related-variables

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNPDTAnAlternativetoIPN/